# socket() fails - errno EPERM - ubuntu

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, sudo

I'm calling socket() fron my user space application, and get an error, with errno = 1 = EPERM.
I'm not root.. Is there something else to do beside calling my application with sudo ?

this is the code :

```
if ((sock=socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)))<0) { //error in socket() }
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: What kind of socket is it that you are trying to open ? Can you post the relevant code associated to your question ?

Comment: If it's a UNIX type socket you probably lack read/write permissions on the file.

Comment: You're trying to create a socket type you do not have permission to create. You should be allowed to create UDP or TCP sockets, but not e.g. a raw socket. So what kind of socket did you try to make ?

Comment: this is the code : 
if ((sock=socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)))<0) 
{
//error in socket()
 }

Comment: You should update your question with this code. I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the processes that are wanting to use `SOCK_RAW` sockets need either having the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability or having a `UID` of *zero* (root), from the man page :

> Only processes with an effective user ID of 0 or the CAP_NET_RAW
>   capability are allowed to open raw sockets.

Comment: great. so I did: $sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep ./my_app 
$./my_app

BUT now I get an error in binding this socket : socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

Comment: great. so I did: $sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep ./my_app 
$./my_app

BUT now I get an error in binding this socket : socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) What capabilities do DGRAM need for binding ?

Comment: What error is set into errno ? What do you mean by bind (simply creating the socket or actually using the syscall `bind`) ? Also, why did you swith from SOCK_RAW to SOCK_DGRAM (used for sending datagrams through a socket interface) ?

Comment: Halim, this is another socket.. the errno I get is in biding, errno EADDRINUSE

Comment: That means that, somewhere in your code, you do want to bind your socket to a port that is already in use. Probably because you did relaunch your server multiple times using the same port (you might want to look about the `SO_REUSEADDR` feature).